# Completing an accordion jQuery feature, I've tried a lot, nothing seems to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'll get straight to the point, I'm trying to complete this accordion effect (when you open one, the others close) and there is about 7 attributes on the accordion. Each one has a PLUS sign so when you open that it should turn into a MINUS sign (via Font Awesome, this part I can take care of, just for context).

**HTML** The `<a>` contains the icon which is a **+** sign and the `ul.checkbox-list` is what needs to be monitored for whether or not it has an `active` class so it can collapse the others. I've gotten somewhat close but then something else happens, I thought maybe another set of eyes could help?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("a[id^='attr']").on("click", function() {

            if( $(this + "ul.checkbox-list").hasClass("visible") ) {
                // Got lost as to what to do here ..
            } else {
                $("a[id^='attr'] > i").removeClass("fa-plus-circle").addClass("fa-minus-circle");
                $("ul.checkbox-list").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $("ul.checkbox-list").slideUp(200);
                $(this).siblings().slideDown("slow");
            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <section>
            <ul id="att7">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="attr7"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> </i> Lumens</a>
                    <ul class="checkbox-list">
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Aged Brass</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Antique Nickel</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Titanium</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Black & Aged Brass</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Titanium</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>    
            </ul> <!-- This is the last attribute in the accordion -->
        </section>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:** The accordion (when opened, contains checkboxes FYI).

Comment: First of all I think you need to deaden your links. Add an event.preventDefault() to your click handler to stop the link from reloading the page or something.

Comment: I do have that, I just didn't think. it was important to include.

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of mistakes in your code. First of all `$(this + "ul.checkbox-list")`  does not work. This is an element, you cannot concat it to  a selecor. Use `$(this).next("ul.checkbox-list")` to find the next elemen (IF it has that class.
Then you mixed up some cases, showing the siblings etc. Your active class and visible class seemed unrelated (though I guess the purpose was to have one on the button the other on the list). In the code I modified I condensed it down to just active class:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
        $("a[id^='attr']").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if( $(this).next("ul.checkbox-list").hasClass("active") ) {
                $(this).next("ul.checkbox-list").slideUp(200).removeClass("active");
            } else {
                $("a[id^='attr'] > i").removeClass("fa-minus-circle").addClass("fa-plus-circle");
                $(this).find(" > i").removeClass("fa-plus-circle").addClass("fa-minus-circle");
                $("ul.checkbox-list").removeClass("active");
                $(this).siblings('ul.checkbox-list').slideUp("slow");
                $(this).next("ul.checkbox-list").slideDown(200).addClass("active");

            }

        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="att7">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="attr7"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"> </i> Lumens</a>
                    <ul class="checkbox-list active">
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Aged Brass</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Antique Nickel</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Titanium</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Black & Aged Brass</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;"> 
                            <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                            <p>Titanium</p>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                            <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>    
            </ul> <!-- This is the last attribute in the accordion -->
        </section>
    </div>
```

Comment: This actually is close to working it just doesn't expand the list, it changes the FA icon and allows the main list to click down but when the FA icon changes the list doesn't show. Any ideas? If so I'll accept, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

several mistakes on your code:

**#1** `$(this + "ul.checkbox-list")` you could simply do a `console.log(this)` to know that `this` is not a string, as the `+` is a abreviation for `concat()` as you would most likely end up doing

```
$("[object HTMLDocument]ul.checkbox-list")
```

**#2** this code

```
.slideUp(200).removeClass("active")
```

is the same as

```
.removeClass("active").slideUp(200)
```

as the `slide` as you can see from the documentation, is an async function, not synchronous, so it will execute the chain right away, and not wait for anything ... to remove the class only when the slide animation ends, you would need to pass it as a callback

```
.slideUp(200, () => ...removeClass("..."))
```

**#3** you are checking for a `visible` class, but in all your code, all you do is handle an `active` class instead...

---

all in all, I would fix and refactor your code into something like this:

*all lines explained for better understanding*

```js
$(function() {
   $("a[id^='attr']").on("click", onClickLink);
});

function onClickLink(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();                   // prevent browser to jump up
  var elm = $(evt.delegateTarget),        // the jquery traget elemnet
      chb = elm.next("ul.checkbox-list"), // the next ul.checkbox-list
      isActive = chb.hasClass("active");  // if the next element is active


  minimizeAll(() => {                     // reset to default position
    if(!isActive) maximizeGroup(elm);     // maximize only if the clicked elm is not active
  });
}

// minimize all elements
function minimizeAll(cb) {
  if($("ul.checkbox-list.active").length === 0 && cb)   // prevent slide up when all are minimized
    return cb();                                        // if callback is passed, use it

  $("a[id^='attr'] > i")                                // find all
    .addClass("fa-plus-circle")                         // add PLUS
    .removeClass("fa-minus-circle");                    // remove MINUS 
  $("ul.checkbox-list").slideUp("slow", () => {         // start sliding up
    $("ul.checkbox-list").removeClass("active");        // when sliding up ends, remove active class
    if(cb) cb();                                        // if callback is passed, use it
  });
}

// maximize only the element group
function maximizeGroup(elm) {
  elm.next("ul.checkbox-list").stop().slideDown(200, () => {  // STOP any previous animation and start sliding down the selected group
    elm.find("> i")                                    // from the clicked element (<a>) find (<i>)
        .removeClass("fa-plus-circle")                 // remove PLUS
        .addClass("fa-minus-circle");                  // add MINUS
    elm                                                // from the clicked element (<a>)
        .next("ul.checkbox-list")                      // select next ul.checkbox-list
        .addClass("active");                           // and add "active" class
  });
}
```

```css
a[id^='attr'] {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

/* default values */
ul ul {
  display: none; 
}
ul ul > li {
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul.checkbox-list.active {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-v8BU367qNbs/aIZIxuivaU55N5GPF89WBerHoGA4QTcbUjYiLQtKdrfXnqAcXyTv" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
    <section>
        <ul id="att7">
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="attr7"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Lumens 1</a>
                <ul class="checkbox-list">
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Aged Brass</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Antique Nickel</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Titanium</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Black &amp; Aged Brass</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Titanium</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
        </ul> <!-- This is the last attribute in the accordion -->
    </section>
    <section>
        <ul id="att8">
            <li>
                <a href="#" id="attr8"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i> Lumens 2</a>
                <ul class="checkbox-list">
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Aged Brass</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Antique Nickel</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Titanium</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Black &amp; Aged Brass</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li> 
                        <div class="roundedTwo" style="">
                        <p>Titanium</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedTwo" name="check" checked="">
                        <label for="roundedTwo"></label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>    
        </ul> <!-- This is the last attribute in the accordion -->
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting this as an error: `TypeError: $(...).slideUp is not a function` very strange.

Comment: try copy paste the code and then change line by line ... if you click "Run code snippet" in the answer, you can see that it runs normally ... same as in [JsBin example](https://jsbin.com/cucalin/4/edit?javascript,output)